# Jquery click not working for input element at first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a jquery date selector from internet and the script was like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#date3").click(function(){
$("#date3").scroller({ preset: 'datetime' });
wheels = [];
wheels[0] = { 'Hours': {} };
wheels[1] = { 'Minutes': {} };
for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
if (i < 16) wheels[0]['Hours'][i] = (i < 10) ? ('0' + i) : i;
wheels[1]['Minutes'][i] = (i < 10) ? ('0' + i) : i;
}
});
});
</script>
```

My problem is that when i first click the input textbox, it doesn't work.
I've to click on the textbox first, click somewhere else in the page, and then again click on the textbox to make it work. Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to solve without change your code you can do like this:--
when your page will load it will work fine now..

```
<!-- creating a dummy button and clicking on it -->
<div style="display: none;"><input type="submit" id="dummy_btn" value="Dummy Btn" /></div>

jQuery('#dummy_btn').trigger('click'); 
});

jQuery(function(){  
   jQuery('#submitid').click(function(){

    });
    jQuery('#dummy_btn').trigger('click'); 
});
```

Comment: Should i implement the jquery along with my earlier script?

Comment: @DeepakJoyJose just add it when you are calling you jquery

Comment: @DeepakJoyJose check i have updated my code.. add it on your html file.

Comment: @DeepakJoyJose will you please post your full code it is working for me when i have tried.

Comment: <input type="text" name="date3" id="date3" class="box" />
is the textbox on which i want to attach the click event... I got a code in which the datepicker shows up on pageload. I modified the code to show popup on click event. But now its not showing correctly :(
@Learner

Comment: @Learner: Thanx for trying to help me friend. Though your answer was not exact, it could guide me to get my solution. thanx a lot